# keep getting a session timeout, can't figure out why, the server should display the message right back

Tags: python, networking, tcp, udp

keep getting a session timeout, can't figure out why, the server should display the message right back. the code is displayed on the bottom, where the first set of code is the client and the second set is server, the first thing you'll see is the output, that is where is shown that there is a session timeout.

```
Client-Server

All Uppercase
All Lowercase
Initial Caps
Exit
Enter Choice: 1
Enter the sentence: the kid had sicknesss
Session timed out
```

This is the client:

```
import socket
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import time
# Address of UDP IP
UDP_IP_ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1' #server set as localhost
# UDP port number
UDP_PORT_NO = 9999
# Display the message
# print('Pinging',UDP_IP_ADDRESS,UDP_PORT_NO)
#create the socket
clientSocket = socket.socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
#sets the timeout at 1 sec
clientSocket.settimeout(1)

choice = 1

try:   
    print("Client-Server")
    # Create a while loop to repeat the process continously
    while True:
        print()
        print("1. All Uppercase")
        print("2. All Lowercase")
        print("3. Initial Caps")
        print("4. Exit")

        while(True):
            choice=input("Enter Choice: ")
            if(choice not in ["1","2","3","4"]):
                print("Invalid Input!")
            else:
                break      

        if choice is "4":
            print( 'Thank you!')
            break
        # Prompt the user to enter the sentence
        sentence=input("Enter the sentence: ")
        message=choice+"-"+sentence

        # Sending sentence and command to the server.
        clientSocket.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'),(UDP_IP_ADDRESS, UDP_PORT_NO))

        #"Receiving login request from the server"
        #print()
        updated_sentence, server = clientSocket.recvfrom(4096)

        updated_sentence = str(updated_sentence)
        updated_sentence = updated_sentence[2:len(updated_sentence)-1]
        print("Updated Sentence from the server: "+updated_sentence)
except socket.timeout:
    print( 'Session timed out')
```

Here is the server code:

```
# The following module to generate randomized lost packets
import random
from socket import *

# Create a UDP socket
# Notice the use of SOCK_DGRAM for UDP packets
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

# Assign IP address and port number to socket
serverSocket.bind(('', 9999))

print('The server is ready to receive on port: 9999')

# Create a 'while-loop' to run the process continoulsy
while True:

    # Receive the client packet along with the address it is coming from
    message,address = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
    message = str(message)
    message = message[2:len(message)-1]

    command = message[0]
    sentence = message[2:]

    # Create an if-statement to check the command.
    if(command == "1"):
        sentence=sentence.upper()
    elif(command == "2"):
        sentence=sentence.lower()
    else:
        words=sentence.split()
        sentence=""
        for word in words:
            sentence = sentence + word[0].upper()+word[1:]+" "

    # Send the modified sentence to the client.
    serverSocket.sendto(sentence.encode('utf-8'), address)
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the server?

Comment: the code of the server is in the bottom. after the line print('session timeout '

Comment: Is it one script file? How are you running the server?

Comment: no, I ran it separate files. client was run first, then the server was executed and thats where I get the the session timeout.

Comment: shouldn’t The server be running before you start the client? Can you show the commands used to run the scripts?